# Adobe PDF error when printing. What's STACK?

Tags: pdf, print-design

I'm receiving a mysterious error when printing a .PDF. The exact message it prints out (wrong linebreaks) is:

> > ERROR: undefinedresult  OFFENDING COMMAND: itransform
> >
> > STACK:
> >
> > 2380.1
> >     3366.1

I've already accepted the error and offending command specifications are too general to be of any help. What I'm wondering about is the STACK details. What is it? Could it give any help whatsoever?

Comment: The numbers under STACK are probably the location on the stack and an error code that was thrown when something wrong was caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"STACK" is a programming term used to describe functions currently in use to accomplish a particular task. Postscript, the technology behind PDFs, is a programming language in its own right. But unless you are a programmer who understands Postscript, that will do little to help troubleshoot the error.

I would say that something happened when the PDF was being created, some odd transformation that the Postscript driver had a hard time understanding, either because the complexity of the effect or there could have been a bug in the driver that created the PDF, that is in turn causing the printer driver to have a hard time.

One workaround that sometimes works is, in Acrobat, go to the Advanced settings in the Print window and select "Print as image." Either way, you will have to troubleshoot your original document (if you can) to see if there is something odd you can clean up before making another PDF.

Comment: You can sometimes narrow the issue down to an individual object by printing pages one at a time, then removing items from the page until the issue no longer exists.